# Can I use HTML5's Canvas element to load a different web-page within a frame?

Tags: javascript, css, html

For example: If i want to load on my webpage within the canvas element another web-page with all its css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old but I stumbled onto this post from google so in the hope of helping others that may also stumble here:

Check this project out, does just what you want.  Please note, that it's far from perfect but its a really impressive feat.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write an html and css parser and renderer in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You want to use an the `<iframe>` tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Bad kitty! w3schools is BAD.

Comment: Why is it so bad? Looks mostly complete to me. But now I'm curious. Any better sources?